# Publish JAX-WS service with Spring and Embedded Jetty 8

Tags: spring, maven, jax-ws, netbeans-7, embedded-jetty

I am trying to add a JAX-WS web service to my Embedded Jetty application.  The web service client will be a .NET application.

My project was created as a Maven application in Netbeans 7.1.1.  It uses Spring 3.0.

I took the following steps to add the JAX-WS to my application:

1. Added jaxws-spring to the pom.xml.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
       <version>1.8</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. In my Spring web services context, configure the WSSpringServlet.

   ```
   webservicesContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new WSSpringServlet()), "/service/*");
   ```
3. Created an implementation class for my service.

   ```
   @WebService(name = "GenerateUEIDService")
   public class GenerateUEIDService {

       @WebMethod(operationName = "generateUniqueIds")
       public String generateUniqueIds() {
           return "Hello World";
       }

   }
   ```
4. Configure my service in the Spring applicationContext.xml file.

   ```
   <bean id="generateUEIDService" class="com.mycompany.GenerateUEIDService"/>

   <wss:binding url="/service/GenerateUEID.svc">
    <wss:service>
     <ws:service bean="#generateUEIDService" />
    </wss:service>
   </wss:binding>
   ```

I didn't use any Web Service creation wizard in Netbeans for Step 3 above.  Instead I created GenerateUEIDService as a normal Java class, but adding the annotations.  Even though I didn't Netbeans did somehow detect this was a Web Service because it created a "Web Services" node in the project view with "GenerateUEIDServiceService" beneath it.  If I expand GenerateUEIDServiceService I see "generateUniqueIds: String".

It seems to build fine.  But when I run the application I get:

> com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class 
>   com.mycompany.jaxws.GenerateUniqueIds is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?

Well no, I haven't run APT to generate anything.  Given my configuration how should I do that?  Do I need to add a plug-in to my pom.xml?  Or was Netbeans magically supposed to generate the wrapper for me?

Please note that my web service client will be .NET.  So I assume I should use the default SOAPBinding of document/literal wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to create a simple Netbeans Maven java application to see if the wrapper classes for the service would be generated automatically.  Turns out they are created dynamically at run-time by the JAX-WS runtime.

```
[exec:exec]
Jul 12, 2012 8:30:05 AM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class com.mycompany.mavenjaxwsjetty.jaxws.Greet
Jul 12, 2012 8:30:05 AM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class com.mycompany.mavenjaxwsjetty.jaxws.GreetResponse
```

So back to my original application (from the original posting above).  I removed the jaxws-spring stuff for unrelated reasons.  I may have made some other changes I can't recall.  And now when I run that application I can see in the logs that the wrapper classes are being created.

So I guess the answer to my question is that Netbeans does not magically create the wrapper classes for me, but rather the jax-ws runtime does.

Still I wonder under what circumstances the wrapper classes wouldn't be generated automatically for me.  Or when I would want to generate my own using wsgen or maven-jaxb2-plugin.  As usual, I guess there are more than one ways to "skin the cat" and each has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate jaxb classes using a Maven plugin. It should look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <!--
        <generatePackage>if you wan to force the package</generatePackage>
        -->
        <generateDirectory>target/jaxb/generate/</generateDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</schemaDirectory>
        <includeSchemas>
            <includeSchema>yourXSDfile.xsd</includeSchema>
        </includeSchemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I haven't created an XSD.  I want my WSDL and XSD to be created dynamically for me.  It seems jaxws runtime is now doing that for me.

Comment: I see. I did not understand your question.